# c# convert object with List field to List using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<RandomObject> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class NewObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RandomObject Item { get; set; }
}
```

How to convert instance of `List<MyObject>` to `List<NewObject>` by field `Items` with LINQ?

Comment: What have you tried? where did your code fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have  variable `myObject` of `MyObject` type. In this case

```
List<NewObject> newObjects = myObject.Items.Select(i => new NewObject
{
    Item = i,
    Id = myObject.Id
}).ToList();
```

If you have variable `myObjects` with list of type `List<MyObject>` then you just need to add `SelectMany`:

```
List<NewObject> = myObjects.SelectMany(o => o.Items.Select(i => new NewObject
{
    Item = i,
    Id = myObject.Id
})).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, the tricky part is how to populate the `Id` property. I somehow feed that `/* some value here */`is just not good enough...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I may be missing something but it is simply `myObject.id`

Comment: @Eser No comments from OP, but sure you are right. Edited answer.

Comment: Too late here, I guess I better go to sleep... can't think straight anymore.

Comment: Yes, `myObject.id`. I also wanted to clarify, how to convert `List<MyObject>` to `List<NewObject>` by field Items? (Edited question)

Comment: @Boome Added your case to answer.